# How to store a set variable in service.ts then use it where I call it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, angular-services

Guys I've got a problem with this:
I have variable
userdata?: any
In my service.ts then I set it in some other component .it works and when I console.log IT /in service.ts/ ,it works. But when I call it in another components it lose its value and become UNDEFINED.

I NEED TO STORE IT LIKE (LOCALSTORAGE) . I DON'T WANT TO USE LOCALSTORAGE. IF there is a way help me plz. Then else tell me how to remove() localStorage ((( when user close the window of browser NOT LOG OUT. Something like ((localStorage.clear().after WINDOWS CLOSED

HELP PLZ

I used localStorage() and got peoblems with storing data after a user close the window of browser and somebody else started using my website again.the data of previus USER still in there.it is not good

Comment: `I NEED TO STORE IT LIKE (LOCALSTORAGE) . I DON'T WANT TO USE LOCALSTORAGE.`, What?

Comment: And stop using CAPS

Comment: I want to store some data in a variable in service.ts  touse them where I need them just like stored variables that stored in localStorage

Comment: Can you create the variable in a parent file and pass it to service.ts and the other component? You may also need to pass in a set function that the child components use to set it.

Comment: This might help: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: How?listen I have a variable in service.ts and set it in a foo.component then I want the variable to store the data I passed it and call it when I need.

Comment: Inpot and output are for child and parent.I stocked with storing some data just like localStorage() but not exactly the LocalStorage().because it store data until the cash be cleared

Comment: It sounds like your issue is that you want to use a variable in service.ts and another file? Currently the 'other file' does not have access to the variable in service.ts. If you create the variable in a parent file you can pass it and a set function service.ts and your 'other file'. If the variable is always set in the parent file (because you're using a function) the value will be kept up to date in the child components.

Comment: So data can't be store in service.ts .they just can be set and use it right away .and if components changes the value would be empty as default.haa?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Wt I'm trying to do is ,storing a variable in service.ts that I set it in another component to use it's value in one other component. when I set it.it gets the value but when I go to another components and call the variable I found it undefined.actualy it lose it's value when I go to another component.but I want to do somthing that store the value I set before

Answer (score 1):

If you want the storage to be cleared when the window is closed, you could always use sessionStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: So it says data will cleared when session ends. How long does it take to be cleared??

Comment: It is cleared immediately when the user closes the tab/window

Comment: But not be cleared across components while using the site without closing the window .haa?

Comment: As long as the tab is still open, any data in sessionStorage will still be there (even if the page is refreshed)